# How to delete a slide that contains a certain text from all the pptx files in multiple directories?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, powerpoint, python-pptx

**I am trying to delete all the slides that contains a specific text ('apple') from all the pptx files in multiple directories. The code below is able to accomplish that.**

```
import os
import glob
import pptx

def delete_slide_with_name(presentation, name):
    new_presentation = pptx.Presentation()
    for slide in presentation.slides:
        include_slide = True
        for shape in slide.shapes:
            if shape.has_text_frame:
                for paragraph in shape.text_frame.paragraphs:
                    for run in paragraph.runs:
                        if name in run.text:
                            include_slide = False
                            break
                    if not include_slide:
                        break
                if not include_slide:
                    break
            if not include_slide:
                break
        if include_slide:
            new_slide = new_presentation.slides.add_slide(slide.slide_layout)
            for shp in slide.shapes:
                el = shp.element
                new_slide.shapes._spTree.insert_element_before(el, 'p:extLst')
    return new_presentation

path = "C:/Study/Thesis/main_project_folder/Test_Sensitive_Data_Script"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".pptx"):
            file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            presentation = pptx.Presentation(file_path)
            new_presentation = delete_slide_with_name(presentation, "apple")
            new_presentation.save(file_path)
```

**But the problem is, although the code is able to delete the slide, it's not able to reproduce a readable file. When I try to open the file, a prompt pops up showing that the file needs to be repaired. After repairing, the content structure of the file has changed.**

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

[image]

**How can I reproduce all the slides exactly as it was without the deleted slide?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you don't just delete the slides rather than adding the slides you want to a new presentation?

```
import os
import glob
import pptx

def delete_slide_with_name(presentation, name):

    xml_slides = presentation.slides._sldIdLst  
    slides = list(xml_slides)
    for i in range(len(slides),0,-1):
        slide = presentation.slides[i-1]
        for shape in slide.shapes:
            if shape.has_text_frame:
                for paragraph in shape.text_frame.paragraphs:
                    for run in paragraph.runs:
                        if name in run.text:
                            xml_slides.remove(slides[i-1])

path = "C:\\Users\\lukeb\\Downloads\\test\\"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".pptx"):
            file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            presentation = pptx.Presentation(file_path)
            delete_slide_with_name(presentation, "apple")
            presentation.save(file_path)
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I did not know you could outright delete the slides, did not see that in the documentation. That's why this go around of adding the slides. @Luke Bowes